# How to match double quote or single quote or unquoted with regular expression?

Tags: regex

I am trying to grab sometext from all three types of inputs, but can't figure out how to deal with the unquoted case.

So far I have:

```
name=['"](.*?)['"]
```

Input:

```
name="sometext"
name='sometext'
name=sometext
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are a C# developer, so you can use the first matching group to ensure it is closed off with the same quote (and thus support `phrase="Don't forget apostrophes"`).

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"=(?:(['""])(.*?)\1|.*)");

string text = @" 
name=""don't forget me""
name='sometext'
name='sometext'
name=sometext
";

foreach (Match m in regex1.Matches(text))
   Console.WriteLine (m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the OR operator `|` to specify the three cases separatly:

```
('[^'"]*')|("[^'"]*")|([^'"]*)
```

Depending on the regex dialect you are using, you have to define non matching groups separated by the OR operators, and matching groups for the words `[^'"]*`.

Comment: ('[^']*')|("[^']*")|([^'"]*)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what could be after 'name=asdf', assume its whitespace or nothing
that delimits the end.

```
name= 
(?:
     (['"])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1    # (1,2)
 |   (\S*)                     # (3)
)
```

Answer is  $2 catted with $3