# How can I find string in quote using Regular Expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text which include this:

```
  "id": "100001470360923", 
  "name": "Đặng Minh Khiêm", 
  "first_name": "Đặng Minh", 
  "last_name": "Khiêm", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/mrkhiem97", 
  "username": "mrkhiem97", 
  "birthday": "10/09/1992", 
  "location": {
          "id": "108458769184495", 
          "name": "Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam"
      },
```

I am trying to use Regular Expression in C# to get 2 strings:
"id": "100001470360923"
"name": "Đặng Minh Khiêm"

```
        String patternID = "\"id\":\"\\d+\"";
        String patternName = "\"name\":\"[\\w]+\"";
        Match matchID = Regex.Match(data, patternID);
        Match matchName = Regex.Match(data, patternName);
```

But it doesn't work with patternName

I don't know how to use pattern. Can someone give me pattern for this ?

Comment: Relevant [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324279/how-to-match-double-quote-or-single-quote-or-unquoted-with-regular-expression?rq=1).

Comment: [RegEx Cheat Sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) - its not that hard to learn with this tool http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: This looks like JSON. Why don't you parse JSON properly instead of writing a flaky solution with regex?

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression isn't working because you have non-word characters (like space) in your name. You could just match anything that isn't a quote, using `[^\"]+`. Here's a full example:

```
String data = "\"id\": \"100001470360923\", \"name\": \"Ð?ng Minh Khiêm\", \"first_name\": \"Ð?ng Minh\", \"last_name\": \"Khiêm\", \"link\": \"https://www.facebook.com/mrkhiem97\", \"username\": \"mrkhiem97\", \"birthday\": \"10/09/1992\", \"location\": { \"id\": \"108458769184495\", \"name\": \"Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam\" },";
String patternID = "\"id\": \"[^\\\"]+\"";
String patternName = "\"name\": \"[^\\\"]+\"";
Match matchID = Regex.Match(data, patternID);
Match matchName = Regex.Match(data, patternName);

Console.WriteLine(matchID.Value);
Console.WriteLine(matchName.Value);
```

This outputs:

```
"id": "100001470360923"
"name": "Ð?ng Minh Khiêm"
```

Of course if this is some other format (it looks very similar to JSON), it would be easier for you to use a library that is intended for parsing that format. Have a look at [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), or a similar class.

Comment: [^\\\"]+
I did not understand so much about this. Could you explain more clearly?
Thank you

Comment: @user1489472: Any character, except \ and ".

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
var pattern = "\"id\":\\s*\"(?<id>[^\"]*)\"\\s*,\\s*\"name\"\\s*:\\s*\"(?<name>[^\"]*)\"";
var match = Regex.Match(strInput, pattern);
var id = match.Groups["id"].Value;
var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
```