# Regex For singlequote and doublequote

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I just wanna know whats the Regex for singlequote and doublequote specifically something like this 1:

**openquote(startswith) + word + closequote(endswith)**

```
(singlequote)word(/singlequote) sample-> 'asdasdasdass'

(doublequote)word(/doublequote) sample-> "asdasdasdass"
```

in c#winforms /thanks .

**--- updated:**

replacing regex within this line:

```
string hoveredWord = r.GetFragment("[a-zA-Z]").Text;
```

thanks!

Comment: you could refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324279/how-to-match-double-quote-or-single-quote-or-unquoted-with-regular-expression

Comment: This is one of my favorite regex playgrounds for .net http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: @SabilValdano i need regex for c# sir

Comment: @ps2goat nice tool right there sir but i dunno how to use that .also what to type in the "Pattern Box" output was always list of numbers then after that a text with @"" c# appears

Comment: you should read up on regex patterns a bit, then you can play around with making your own or verify that patterns others give you will work.  Source= string you want to find the patterns in. pattern = plain regex pattern-- do not add the @" to the beginning or " at the end as is shown in the result list.  The result list shows you all the matches that your current pattern will return based on your source.  The matches can be blank if the pattern is not what you expected.  The @"" text is the pattern to use in C#-- the @ in front of the string means you don't have to escape C# commands

Comment: ^ e.g., to output a newline on a console app, you add \n to your string.  But if you want that new line character sequence to print to the console, you have to use \\n to escape the slash.  In your case, you didn't have anything in the pattern box and so the results were really just counting the number of characters in your source string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following *RegEx* is for **Single Quotation sign + Some Texts + Single Quotation sign** *('asdasdasdass')*:

```
Regex regexString = new Regex(@"'[^']*'");
```

The following *RegEx* is for **Double Quotation sign + Some Texts + Double Quotation sign** *("asdasdasdass")*:

```
Regex regexString = new Regex(@"""[^""]*""");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex pattern :

```
Former example : ^\'\w+\'
Later example : ^\"\w+\"

^ : match the beginning of the string
\' or \" : match the single quote or double quote
\w+ : match the alpha-numeric characters and underscore
```